# The instance of entity type ‘Bus’ cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {‘Id’} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the Expedition Entity in my project.

```
     [Table("Expeditions")]
     public class Expedition
{

       public int Id { get; set; }
       public Bus Bus { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey("Bus")]
       public int BusId { get; set; }
}
```

And Expedition entity have a foreign key. Foreign key from the Bus Entity.

I create an EpeditionDTO with the information from the front-end.Want try to convert ExpeditionDTO to Expedition and add them to the database.

```
public void Add(ExpeditionDTO item)
        {
            try
            {
                Bus Bus = _mapper.Map<Bus>(item.Bus);
                var expedition = new Expedition()
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Bus = Bus,
                    BusId = Bus.Id
                };
                _expeditionRepository.Add(expedition);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

And my Add method like that:

```
public virtual void Add(T Entity)
        {
            _context.Add<T>(Entity);
        }
```

When I try this i get this error.

The instance of entity type ‘Bus’ cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {‘Id’} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using ‘DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging’ to see the conflicting key values.

How can i solve this problem.

Comment: You are creating a new Bus to assign to your Expedition. What you should be doing is retrieving the existing bus from the data store, OR actually just assigning the BusId would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ou should pass only the `BusId`

```
var expedition = new Expedition()
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    BusId = Bus.Id
                };
```